Can samples be grouped for principal component analysis? Are there any tests needed?
I have two groups of people, those who are involved in public affairs and those who are not. At the same time, I have five types of capital for these people. I want to explore the mix of capital between participants and non-participants. Is there any need for tests before grouping PCA? (I have tried to merge samples, but there is no obvious grouping.)

Hello and welcome on CrossValidated! What do you mean by "grouping PCA"? You might be already aware of that, but to explore the differences between participants and non-participants, you could use the "participant" variable as a supplementary categorical variable. See https://pca4ds.github.io/using-supplementary-elements.html#nominal-supplementary-variables for a discussion. If your favorite statistical software implements PCA, it's likely to offer an option to use supplementary variables with it; referring to its documentation may give you additional info on how to use this method.
